# Replace null values with '' 'sem:sparql' output json in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8

I using ML `8.0-6.3`

I am using `sem:sparql()` function to run the `SPARQL` queries.

If there is no triple for a particular variable(`variables are in OPTIONAL block`) I am getting `null` value in the JSON output.

Is there any work around in MarkLogic to replace the `null` values with `""`.

**Like:**

**coming output:**

```
{
    "ncFacetIri": "http://www.test.com/facet/UL",
    "acronym": "UL",
    "acronym1": null
}
```

**expected json output:**

```
{
    "ncFacetIri": "http://www.test.com/facet/UL",
    "acronym": "UL",
    "acronym1": ""
}
```

This way I am converting the `sem:sparql` output to JSON objects:

```
<a>{sem:sparql($query)}</a>/json:object ! json:object(.)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) for that:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?type (COALESCE(?l, "") as ?label)
WHERE {
  ?subject rdf:type ?type.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?subject rdfs:label ?l.
  }
}
```

HTH!